# Android Studio Kotlin - How to display 2 digit number in text?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

On creating a timer In Android Studio Kotlin.

I'd like to display the time value as it's 2 digit number like '01:04:07'.

Please see the below.

[image]

[image]

At this point, how do I change the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) as below:

```
  val f: NumberFormat = DecimalFormat("00")
  timerDisplay.text = "${f.format(lapshours)}:${f.format(lapsMin)}:${f.format(lapsSec)}"
```

Comment: I am happy to help you :). Please accept it as an answer, it will be helpful for other users

Answer (score 23):

Simply use `String.format()` like:

```
timerDisplay.text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", lapsHours, lapsMinutes, lapsSeconds)
```

Comment: HI Aminography, Just tried and this one works as well. I love the simple way. Many Thanks! :)

Comment: If you really want to do things right, just call an old C function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your extension function on Int like

```
fun Int.format(): String{
    return if(this<10 && this>=0) "0"+this.toString() else this.toString()
}
```

simple call format() function on your Int variable to get your required format.

```
timerDisplay.text = "${lapsHours.format()} : ${lapsMinutes.format()} : ${lapsSeconds.format()}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip. I needed it, but I did it this way to simplify

```
fun Int.format(): String{
    return if(this in 0..9) "0" + this.toString() else this.toString()
}
```

Comment: Laudemir, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: Awkward but works.